# where can I find the parameter in Hydro instead of "velocity" in groovy?

Tags: ros, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i use hydro to work through TF tutorial. it says There is no attribute "Velocity" in the module.(listener part) and I tried to change it to cmd_vel but it still does not work......
where can I find the parameter in Hydro instead of "velocity" in groovy ?? There may be other parameter changed in Hydro, how can I get them??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134756/where-can-i-find-the-parameter-in-hydro-instead-of-%22velocity%22-in-groovy-??/) by [archer0517](https://answers.ros.org/users/12656/archer0517/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [archer0517](https://answers.ros.org/users/12656/archer0517/) on 2014-03-02**:
the tutorial's link: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29

the problem is about line 19 of "nodes/turtle_tf_listener.py"

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2014-03-03**:
those tutorials are a bit outdated. You could file an issue: https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues?state=open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the command message type in turtlesim has changed from turtlesim/Velocity to geometry_msgs/Twist.

I've updated the tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0